# Create unordered list from column in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

Table A lists playerID(PK), Name, etc.

Table B lists awardID(PK), playerID(FK), playerOfWeek, allStar, etc.

As some players can have more than one award (such as been awarded player of the week twice -- they would have a different awardID #), how could I create an ordered list to display the value in the appropriate player award column?

I'm first using a function call

```
  function create_unordered_list($listitems) {
  echo "<ul>";
  foreach($listitems as $value) {
  echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
  }

   echo "</ul>";
  }
```

I'm storing the result of the column in:

```
  $All_Star = $row['award_AllStar'];
```

Then, I'm trying to echo out the list:

```
  echo create_unordered_list ($All_Star);
```

Any help, very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `print_r($listitems)` inside the function and show us what it is printing.

Comment: it is not printing anything.

Comment: Error tells me : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in function

Comment: So your query doesn't return anything, try to run it in phpMyAdmin.